# Nested Views are not rendering

Tags: android, view, nested

new to this site so sorry if this question is inappropriate, or in the wrong section.

Android:

I have written a custom button class which extends View and works just fine. Now I want to create a numeric keypad class which uses several of these custom buttons arranged in a particular way, which I can then use in a phone dialler app. I can build the keypad from within the app's main activity, and it seems ok, but I want to build this keypad inside its own class for easy re-use. When I move the code into its own class I get either errors or nothing drawn on screen. I think part of the problem is what class the child views are being added to.

Here's my code in the main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);
    LcarsButton numericPad[] = new LcarsButton[10]; //array of buttons

    LinearLayout rows[] = new LinearLayout[3];

    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        rows[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
            int k = (i * 3) + j;
            numericPad[k] = new LcarsButton(this);
            numericPad[k].label = "" + k;
            rows[i].addView(numericPad[k]); 
        }
        layout.addView(rows[i]);
    }
```

It loops through the array numericPad, assigning 3 buttons to each 'row', then 3 'row's to the 'layout'. This works fine.
Here's the code as seen in the class constructor:

```
    public class LcarsNumPad extends LinearLayout {

    public LcarsNumPad(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LcarsButton numericPad[] = new LcarsButton[10];


    layout.setOrientation(1);
    LinearLayout rows[] = new LinearLayout[3];

    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        rows[i] = new LinearLayout(context);
        for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
            int k = (i * 3) + j;
            numericPad[k] = new LcarsButton(context);
            numericPad[k].label = "" + k;
            rows[i].addView(numericPad[k]); 
        }
        layout.addView(rows[i]);
    }
```

As you can see the only differences in the code are to accommodate the context of each particular piece of code. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: where you are setting Layout params?

Comment: I was setting them in the declaration of the new LinearLayout() but as that wasn't working I stripped the code down to essentials. Am I right in thinking you don't need them to at least get something onto the display? I'm sure i've used just LinearLayout(context) before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the reason of Error is you are using `layout` variable which is defined in `onCreate()`. You need to pass the `rows` array to the main activity and from there you can add it to the layout.

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying to keep the nested layout inside the class if possible. Would it be better if I did the layout.addView(rows[i]) in the onCreate() method? Obviously I would have to pass it rows[] and loop through it again...

Comment: The reason for this is that I'd like to be able to create pre-defined groups of controls which can be quickly dropped into other apps without complicating their activity code

Comment: Then in the constructor of you custom Numpad, pass the Layout where you want to add your rows, so that you can get the layout object in that class.

Comment: aaAAAaaah that sounds like just the ticket! So something like ...    
   
    public class LcarsNumPad extends LinearLayout {    
    public LcarsNumPad(Context context, Layout layout) {  
    ...  
    layout.addView(rows[i]);

Comment: Brilliant! Just tried it and this seems to have done the trick :) Thanks, Creator

Comment: As a noob to this site, is there anything I can do to indicate that you solved my problem?

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it helped you, or if it's the most correct answer, you can also tick the green checkmark, which'll accept my answer. :D

Comment: Cool :) not got enough reputation to upvote yet, but I've ticked you. For anyone following this the constructor should have LinearLayout not Layout in the parameters

Comment: UPDATE: Creator's method works great for rendering nested views but I noticed a bit of an issue - as the layout.add() is occurring in the constructor, the child views are added directly to the parent (their grandparents, I suppose) when you declare a variable as a Numpad, not when you addView(numpad) as it should be. This can cause problems. The actual answer, I have found, is to just use ".addView(button)" in the constructor of numpad, which adds the children to the class itself instead of the parent. - then nothing appears until you use activity.addView(numpad);, when it displays correctly.